# How Do I add an ORDER BY statement to a VBA Search Function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access 2010 Form in which I have a Search "button." The Search works perfectly, but I would like it to return records ordered by ID, LastName, FirstName, and I can't figure out how to do it. Below is the working VBA that I am currently using. Any help is greatly appreciated>

```
Private Sub SearchCrystals_Click()
If Len(cboSearchField) = 0 Or IsNull(cboSearchField) = True Then
        MsgBox "You must select a field to search."

    ElseIf Len(txtSearchString) = 0 Or IsNull(txtSearchString) = True Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a search string."

    Else

        'Generate search criteria
        GCriteria = cboSearchField.Value & " LIKE '*" & txtSearchString & "*'"

        'Filter qry_crystals_specimens_formsearchDNC based on search criteria
        Form_frm_crystals_specimens_master.RecordSource = "select * from qry_crystals_specimens_formsearchDNC where " & GCriteria
        Form_frm_crystals_specimens_master.Caption = "qry_crystals_specimens_formsearchDNC (" & cboSearchField.Value & " contains '*" & txtSearchString & "*')"

        'Close frmSearch
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_search_crystals_specimens"

        MsgBox "Results have been filtered."

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a ORDER BY clause to your SELECT string?

Comment: I have, right after GCRITERIA, but perhaps I did not format it correctly. ??

Comment: Would it not be better to apply a filter and order by on the form rather than changing the record source?

Comment: I'm not trying to change the record source. I just want the records returned to be sorted. When I add an ORDER BY statement to the form, it works when the form is viewed, but it does not work when the form is searched. I'm not sure how to apply a filter to the form. Maybe a filter WITH and Order By on the form would work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
Dim Sql As String

Sql = "select * from qry_crystals_specimens_formsearchDNC where " & GCriteria & " order by LastName, FirstName, ID"

Debug.Print Sql

Form_frm_crystals_specimens_master.RecordSource = Sql
```

Comment: Debug your GCriteria string.

Comment: That's what I've been attempting to do for the past couple of days with no luck.

Comment: That did it, my friend :)! Thanks for sticking in there to help a guy with limited VBA skills. Much appreciated!